# Plot amount of turtle going through x time the model

Tags: plot, distance, counting

I am working on my first Netlogo program and I blocking on something. 
As saied in the title, I want to create a plot which can count amount of turtles going through x times of the distance of the model. 
For this I add an new variable inside turtles call memory-of-distance for keeping in memory the distance of each turtle.

I succed to create something manualy but I cannot find a way to transform it into an automatic plot. 
This the way I do it now. It's going until 30 and I need to create each time a globals variable. After I ask to the plot to have a pen for each global variable.

```
set count-model-distance1 0
set count-model-distance2 0
set count-model-distance3 0
set count-model-distance4 0
set count-model-distance5 0
 ask turtles [
    if memory-of-distance >= 129 * 1 [ set count-model-distance1 count-model-distance1 + 1]
    if memory-of-distance >= 129 * 2 [ set count-model-distance2 count-model-distance2 + 1 set count-model-distance1-oxygens count-model-distance1 - 1]
    if memory-of-distance >= 129 * 3 [ set count-model-distance3 count-model-distance3 + 1 set count-model-distance2-oxygens count-model-distance2 - 1]
    if memory-of-distance >= 129 * 4 [ set count-model-distance4 count-model-distance4 + 1 set count-model-distance3-oxygens count-model-distance3 - 1]
    if memory-of-distance >= 129 * 5 [ set count-model-distance5 count-model-distance5 + 1 set count-model-distance4-oxygens count-model-distance4 - 1]
```

My model lenght is 129 patches and distance is counting with patches. That's why superior to 129 patches.

There is an example with number: an turtle have as memory-of-distance 400, it's superior to 387 (129 *3) so it's more than three time model distance. Do it for turtle present inside the model and to create plot capable of each tick to show how many turtle are at 2 or 3 or 4 ect. Here are turtle is 3 so +1 for counter 3 but when it will travel 4 times the model, it will be 4.

You will find just above how I do with the plot. I ask at each global variable a counting.

[plottings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxXIc.png)

I hope it's clear otherwise ask me to explain again or details.

Thanks you in advance for your help ! 
Anton

Comment: Please edit your question to have the code (not an image). You can use the { } to format it. Also, it would be good if you gave an example with numbers to show the working out of what you want to do.

Comment: Ok JenB ! I will do it

Comment: Did it @JenB , I hope it's like you wanted.